# PHP - Log in Script Not Creating Sessions

Tags: php, session

I have a log in script where I have been able to successfully make users, and log in. Now my issue is that whenever I try to use my method of protecting pages, being seeing if there is a SESSION for 'user' if not it directs you back to the login page.

Here is me checking for the session,

```
require("common.php"); 


if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 

    header("Location: login"); 

    die("Redirecting to login"); 
}
```

Here is where I am setting my session, I am ONLY setting a session_start(); on login.php

```
if($login_ok) 
    { 

        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 

        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

        header("Location: home?worked=1"); 
        die("Redirecting to: home?worked=1");
        session_start(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print("Login Failed."); 
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
}
```

What this does, is I log in, and it will process and bring me to my home page, then process the header back to the login page acting as if I am not logged in. I tested a false login and it IS telling that its the correct login.

Thanks for any help, I'm pulling my hair out here!

Necro

**EDIT**

I moved session_start(); to the top of my common.php, and everything is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You have `session_start();` after `$_SESSION['user'] = $row;`
Actually you have it after a `die();` command. Nothing happens after that.

Put `session_start();` at the top of PHP in every page (pref common.php since you have one) not just one page.

Comment: Woops. I misread your comment. This worked! Thank you so much. I am still getting used to placement in PHP...Its so darn picky!

Comment: Well, logical to anyone that realizes the logistical aesthetics behind it...To me I'm still thinking most of the time you can plop anything as long as its in tandem with another script and it will work. But I get you completely. I need to take a hard look at the order of operations behind things like this.

Comment: The order is simple: the order in which you write things that execute is the order in which they get executed. Things don't work in tandem. If they did, trying to form a logical process would be impossible.

Comment: I take everything back. You are right. Lets not argue. I don't want to sleep on the couch.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to set the `session_start()` on top

Answer (score 1):

You need to put session_start(); on every page you want to use the session.